# woo commerce replace dropdown product variable with label where there is an attribute that has only one selection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm completely new on wp Woo Commerce.
Using wp AllImport I try to get products from the site bellow but for usability I have one big problem - users need to select all options even there is only one option, to buy a variable product.
Is there a solution to display variable products in woo commerce as in [this website](http://www.duffells.com/products/Stanley-150-Euro-Mortice-Latch-Case-Flat-Strike-31414.aspx)?

and orphan attribute to be shown as label but in same time to be selected?

Please note the dropdown is show only if there is another attribute (variant) with different value.

I've try to filter orphan values from my Array() but the product has not full details as I wish.

Please see my [work result](http://ymgsecure.com/product/briton-2130b-size-2-6-overhead-closer-with-backcheck/)

As you can see you need to select all dropdowns to buy the product.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your site is showing 404. There is this filter `woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html`, *but* there's no argument passed to that filter telling you which attribute you are dealing with. For the time being, you'll need to do a string match, but I'll suggest a PR.

Comment: I've edit my website link ... Thank you helgatheviking

Comment: You can also override `wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options()` to customize. If I were going to try this (and I can't right now) I'd probably add a CSS class to hide the `<select>` input and then just display the title. I suggest this because I think the scripts might need the `<select>` element in order to function properly.

Comment: kindly ask you where I can find this function wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options() ?

Comment: You can search the WooCommerce folder with any decent text editor. Or you can find it in [github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/b12f74a263d47e908e64ede007249dfe834ee166/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1976)

Comment: thanks again sorry about my stupid question